# How to get all selectors by class name that were dynamically appended in vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to get / count how many elements with a common class `target` name are "available". None on those elements physically exists in the DOM. Those items have been added later when the page was fully loaded.

Below

```
var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
```

when I `console.log(targets);` **I get** `[]`.

When I click those square brackets, they expand and `target` items seems to appear but next to them there's a message:

> Object value at left was snapshotted when logged, value below was
> evaluated just now.

So I assume that I did `console.log` when DOM hasn't been populated with `target` elements yet. How do I get information about dynamically added elements?

EDIT:

I checked hsh's functions and

```
document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
    console.log(targets.length);
    /**
     * If I have 40 target elements, this will be called 40 times :/ showing first bunch of zeros then finally number will reach to 40
     */
});

/**
 * So this would be ideally (called only once) but this always shows empty array and 0
 */
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('marker');
    console.log(targets); // always shows []
    console.log(targets.length); // always shows 0

    //while I can play with those target selectors in Chrome Dev Tools
});
```

PS. No jQuery please.

Comment: Include your script as the very last thing in the `<body>` tag. That way the Dom has rendered before you run your script.

Comment: @jh3y — That won't catch any that have been dynamically added (unless the script which adds them runs before this one *and* isn't asynchronous) … which is what the question is asking about.

Comment: Exactly! @Quentin is right! That's the point. To catch dynamically added stuff.

Comment: @jh3y — No, it won't: http://jsbin.com/fibume/1/edit?html,output

Comment: I'm extremely confused by the use of the word "selectors" here, but the fact that there are 4 upvotes suggests that there is something I'm missing.

Comment: By saying selector, I mean something I would catch in jQuery as `var targets = $('.targets');`. Simple HTML like `<div class="target">lorem ipsum</div>`.

Comment: If it were simply that the script that adds the elements ran before the script that finds them, having it as last in the DOM would work fine [jsbin....](https://jsbin.com/yorivazeqe/2/edit?html,console). However as you seek dynamic behaviour you need to be calling the `querySelector` after that code has been run say within a function within a change event much like the provided answer.

Comment: It might as well be me that asks the bleedingly obvious question: why not log the results *after* the code that adds the elements has run?

Comment: If you don't add a `jquery` tag, the assumption is that you don't want jquery answers.

Comment: OK, I removed jQuery tag. Just vanilla JS.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess by "selectors" he means "elements".

Comment: @torazaburo, they didn't help me directly but that was just because I didn't explain where and how exactly I have to use it. Let me accept the answer that was closest to the final solution. BTW. Your comments suggests a little bit that the main purpose of your activity on SO are just points and badges. ;)

Comment: @slick An odd comment, what comments do you think suggest that? If that is my main purpose, it is not working very well. My main purpose is to help people out and also ensure that SO has solid answers for later folks to find and refer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call your check script in `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  console.log(targets);
});
```

Also you can use `DOMSubtreeModified` event if you're expecting that something will be added during the runtime.

```
document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
  var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('target');
  console.log(targets);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLLjeLhr/1)

Comment: @hsh, thank you but your code doesn't work as expected. Please see my edited question. `DOMSubtreeModified` is triggered as many times as the quantity of `.target` items. So `DOMContentLoaded` would be great because it runs just once but it returns empty array and 0 as length.

Comment: Why would I need to do this when the result from `getElementsByClassName` is updated dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very confusing.

> I need to get / count how many selectors

A "selector" is a way of targeting/addressing elements. A selector is used to find, or match, elements. For instance, `.foo` is a **selector**, which matches **elements** with the class `"foo"`. In your case, you mean you want to get/count how many **elements**.

> I need to get / count how many elements with a common class target name are "available". None on those elements physically exists in the DOM.

So the elements are available, but not in the DOM? What does that mean?

> Those items have been added later when the page was fully loaded.

What do you mean by fully loaded? Same as `DOMContentLoaded`? Or fully loaded in the sense that all JS to help build the page has also completed?

The easiest thing to do is to wait until all the logic which adds elements has finished running, then evaluate `getElementsByClassName`. Why can't you do that?

If for some reason you evaluate `getElementsByClassName` earlier, or on page load, you will find that at any given point in time it **still** reflects an up-to-date list of elements, since `getElementsByClassName` returns a **live** collection, which is updated as your document changes. That also means you don't need to run anything at load time, or watch arcane events such as `DOMSubtreeModified`.

At any point in time, including after your elements have been added, the value of `targets` will include all elements with that class, and `targets.length` will give the total number of such elements.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> `elements` is a **live** HTMLCollection of found elements.

Comment: So how to get them once all have been added? Maybe I forgot to add that I append let say 40 items and that's all. New items will never be added again.

Comment: After they have been added, the value of `targets` will include all of them, and `targets.length` will give the total number.